# Is there term for thermophilic-halophilic plants and if so, what is it?

Tags: botany, terminology

I know that in botany there is a wide classification for plants that can survive in hot deserts (semi-arid or arid) and harsh climates such as 4-season countries with a tendency to droughts each year (such as Palestine).
This classification, as I understand it, is *thermophilic plants* (hot loving).

But there is also the classification *thermophilic* plants which are also *halophilic* (salt loving), i.e. *can survive and even flourish in extremely low and salty ground*? Examples of such plants are found in the [Ein Feshkha reserve near the Dead Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_Feshkha) in Israel and other similar Thypa and other plants reserves near the Dead Sea (current) shorelines in Israel, Palestine and Jordan.

Is there term for thermophilic-halophilic plants and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, at least in other biological contexts, such organisms are often simply referred to as being **thermohalophiles** (or as being **thermohalophilic**).

Examples of the use of these words:

*Bacteria*:

- Mavromatis, K., Ivanova, N., Anderson, I., Lykidis, A., Hooper, S.D., Sun, H., Kunin, V., Lapidus, A., Hugenholtz, P., Patel, B. and Kyrpides, N.C., 2009. Genome analysis of the anaerobic **thermohalophilic** bacterium *Halothermothrix orenii*. PLoS One, 4(1).
- Denger, K., Warthmann, R., Ludwig, W. and Schink, B., 2002. *Anaerophaga thermohalophila* gen. nov., sp. nov., a moderately **thermohalophilic**, strictly anaerobic fermentative bacterium. International journal of systematic and evolutionary microbiology, 52(1), pp.173-178.
- Pereira, M.M., Antunes, A.M., Nunes, O.C., da Costa, M.S. and Teixeira, M., 1994. A membrane‐bound HIPIP type center in the **thermohalophile** *Rhodothermus marinus*. FEBS letters, 352(3), pp.327-330.

*Biochemistry*:

- Amoozegar, M.A., Salehghamari, E., Khajeh, K., Kabiri, M. and Naddaf, S., 2008. Production of an extracellular **thermohalophilic** lipase from a moderately halophilic bacterium, *Salinivibrio sp*. strain SA‐2. Journal of basic microbiology, 48(3), pp.160-167.

I'll note that I haven't found evidence of *plants* being referred to in this specific manner, but read the example papers below for use of the related phrases "**thermohalophyte** vegetation" and "**thermohalophytes**", respectively:

- Accogli, R., Nutricati, E., Famà, L., Medagli, P., Manno, D., De Bellis, L., Marchiori, S. and Colasante, M., 2008. Iris revoluta Colas., natural hybrid origin species: characterization and preservation problems. Plant Biosystems, 142(1), pp.162-165.
- Vekhov, N.V., 1996. Thermal and freshwater springs of the Chukchi Peninsula: Unique subarctic ecosystems. Part ii. flora. Polar Geography, 20(3), pp.209-220.

Is this [word-blending](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/91306/139534) approach the best or most appropriate? I Couldn't say; but there is certainly prior  precedence for combining the habit adjectives into "thermohalo-".